# What is background color code of Message Dark mode

Tags: android

Android Message for Android app released Dark Mode feature and I am interested in with it's background color. 
But I can't know how to find the exactly color code of background (colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark) of this dark theme.

Can anyone tell me it's color codes? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: May be `#252628` why don't you use any color picker for that?

Comment: @NileshRathod, i know we can get color code from image from some tools but it not really exactly.

Comment: what app is this ?

Comment: Use this https://html-color-codes.info/colors-from-image/ website, Upload image and click anywhere on image to get color code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title bar color:

hex #202124

hsl(224,5,13)

rgb(32,33,36)

Background color:

hex #202124

hsl (224,5,13)

rgb (32,33,36)